# why does adding tab delimiter causes error in csv read?

Tags: python

I am attempting to read from a tab delimited .txt file

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"L:\Facility\Dynos\Cell 2 dyno\Quality statistics\2023\quality_stats.txt",sep='\t')
print(df.columns.tolist())
```

For what ever reason adding the `sep='\t'` causes the code to fail;

```
line 912, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
```

omitting `sep='\t'` I do get a single value as an answer;

`['Date\tStart Time\tProject OK\tProject Failed\tTest Displacement [km]\tProject Displacement [km]']`

Comment: You could try saving the file as a .tsv and running the code again?

Comment: Hello, please add error traceback (as text) and possibly a few significant lines from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the `\` in your separator -> `\` is an escape character in python, so you would need `sep='\\t'`

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Comment: @James if this answer worked, please accept it.